# Расплывается текст, если цвет фона с Альфа-каналом

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

Добрый день. Рисую свой контрол в WinForms. На рисунке 3 прямоугольника, у центрального Альфа-канал 255, у верхнего и нижнего 100.
Вот результат:
[image: То что получается]

Для отображения использую Rectangle. Цвет использую постоянный, меняется только составная Альфа-канала. Цвет задаю через `Color.FromARGB(a,r,g,b);` Шрифт использую постоянный.
Как сделать, чтоб не расплывался текст, если фон у меня немного прозрачный?
Чем меньше составная Альфа-канала, тем больше расплывается текст (он не жирный, он обычный).

Вот пример кода:

```
var rect = new Rectangle(locat, sizeRect);
Color rectColor = (t[j].RectColor != null) ? (Color)t[j].RectColor : defaultRectColor;
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(rectColor), rect);
Font font = t[j].RectFont != null ? (Font)t[j].RectFont : this.Font;
var textcolor = t[j].TextColor != null ? (Color)t[j].TextColor : this.ForeColor;
g.DrawString(t[j].Description, font, new SolidBrush(textcolor), rect);
```

Comment: Приведите инициализацию массива `t[]`.

Comment: Инициализация и все необходимые для работы действия выполнены. Здесь видна часть кода работающей программы. Я думаю здесь неучтенная фишка отображения текста на фоне с прозрачностью (Альфа-каналом). И Моя задача - найти эту "фишку".

Comment: Здесь нету значений `defaultRectColor`, `t[j].TextColor`, `this.ForeColor`